# Change dotenv configuration when deploying to Heroku/production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an ajax call that relies on an API key as part of the request URL. I am using dotenv to hide that key. It works fine when I run it locally, but once deployed on Heroku, it gives me back a:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '________' of null
```

It looks as though it's returning null back (but it's totally fine in development). I'm wondering if I have to change any of the settings relating to dotenv when pushing up to Heroku / for production?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to the file named `.env` as `dotenv`. Every variable in that file that you need on Heroku must be defined in Heroku config vars : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

The `.env` file is an easy way to replicate the Heroku config vars `locally`. That way your code is prepared to read configuration data from config vars. For code running on Heroku you need to set the heroku config vars.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! Exactly what the issue was. Needed to set Heroku's config vars and now it works correctly. Really appreciate the help!